# Jquery setTimeOut Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

How would this be written in Jquery?. I tried using delay() but doesn't seem to work in canvas.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this the android rotateAnimation method or something else?

Comment: Sorry, it's a jquery plugin. http://www.dariancabot.com/projects-2/jgauge/

Comment: Hmmm, since that plugin doesn't seem to have a callback handler, and short of rewriting it to have one, you could use a setTimeout call to create a delay.

Comment: What's wrong with writing `20`, btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('div.jgauge .needle').rotateAnimation(-200 + 220);
setTimeout (function(){$('div.jgauge .needle').rotateAnimation(220 + -200);},1000);
```